# angular 2 same component in multiple places with different business logic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, generic-programming, use-case

Sorry for the length of the question. I have some design issues.

I have a component which takes roomView array as @Input and displays them in HTML page.

```
export class RoomView {
"id": string,
"name": string,
"markerIcon": string,
"backgroundColorClass": string
}
```

**room-browser.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'room-browser',
    templateUrl: 'room-browser.component.html',
})
export class RoomBrowserComponent {
    @Input() roomsList: RoomView[]: = [];
}
```

**room-browser.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let room of roomsList">
    <div class="room.backgroundColorClass">
    {{room.name}}
    <i class="{{room.markerIcon}}"></i>
    </div>
```

[image]

my generic room component provides roomView to room-browser

**generic-room.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'room',
    templateUrl: 'room.html',
})
export class GenericRoomComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() source: string;

    private roomView: RoomView[] = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.roomView = // i am getting this from backed successfully
        // here I need to decide marker icon and background color class based on some criteria which differs from page to page
        // I have different sections like space, energy, maintenance etc...
        // for space, needs to get space usage for rooms from backend and then decide color
        // for energy, needs to get energy usage and decide the colors
        // for maintenance, needs get devices information of rooms and decide color

    //I want to avoid something like this
    if (this.source === 'space') {
         // get space usage
    } else if (this.source === 'energy') {
         // get space usage
    } else if (this.source === 'maintenance') {
         // get device info and decide color
    }
    }

}
```

**room.html**

```
<room-browser [roomsList]="roomView"></room-browser>
```

**space.html**

```
<room [source]="space"></room>
```

**energy.html**

```
<room [source]="energy"></room>
```

**maintenance.html**

```
<room [source]="maintenance"></room>
```

I need to decide marker icon and background color class based on some criteria which differs from page to page.

I have different sections like space, energy, maintenance etc... for space, needs to get space usage for rooms from backend and then decide color, for energy needs to get energy usage and decide the color and for maintenance needs get devices information of rooms and decide color

So how and where can I implement this use case specific logic inside a generic component?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your scenario, but you can add color properties to the GenericRoomComponent for each of these colors and pass them to the child component via additional @Input properties.

OR you can build a service that retains those values and have each of the child components read those values.

Comment: To add the color property I have different logic based on whether I'm using room component inside space, energy or maintenance. For space I need to get space usage from backend and decide the color like of usage less than 2hours then red color etc.. for maintenance section I need to get devices of room and Mark color red if devices are having error.  So my question is where and how to implement this logic?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a component across multiple modules, you'll need to create a "shared" module and add that component the shared module's exports. Then you add that shared module into your other modules imports.